# imagick readImageBlob giving 'uable to open file' error

Tags: php, imagick

I am getting the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `/tmp/magick-2244K7gyKdSJDqKW': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2658' in /var/www/nodeviz-read-only/www/NodeViz/library/GraphVizExporter.php:454

The relevant code referenced is here:

```
    $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setFormat('svg');
    #remove labels from the raster version
    $im->readImageBlob(preg_replace('/<text.+\/text>/m', "", $this->svgString));
```

I'm not sure where to look to start debugging this. Any suggestions as to what could be causing this error would be appreciated. (I didn't write code, I'm just trying to use it.)

Comment: Can you post the SVG string?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and resolved it by installing the following dependencies:

`sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxml2-dev librsvg2-dev librsvg2-bin`

That worked for me, but if it doesn't work for you:

Recompile ImageMagick (whichever version suits you):

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/7.0.8-7.tar.gz
tar xzf 7.0.8-7.tar.gz
cd ImageMagick-7.0.8-7
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-rsvg --with-xml
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

Add the latest Imagick PHP extension:

```
pear config-set preferred_state beta
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
pecl install imagick-beta
```

Make sure the imagick.so is loaded in PHP and you should be good to go.